# Unable to send FiX message from client

Tags: java, spring-boot, quickfixj, quickfixj-spring-boot-starter

I am new to the world of FiX and currently learning how to send fix messages between apps in Java.

I came across this [Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/README.adoc) which basically reduces the boiler plate code.
I have two spring boot starters; one acting as the initiator (client) and the other is the server (acceptor).

I've had a look at their examples on the repo and even though it was pretty defined with the multiple scenarios, I'm having trouble sending a simple FiX message from my client to the server.

My client code consists of a controller in which when the endpoint is called; it sends the following fix message (my main class is literally your usual spring main class but it's annnotated with `@EnableQuickFixJClient` and `@SpringBootApplication`):

```
@RestController
public class SendMessageViaRest
{
@Autowired
QuickFixJTemplate quickFixJTemplate;

@GetMapping("/bob")
public void sendFix()
{
  System.out.println("HERHER");

  Message message = new Message();
  quickfix.Message.Header header = message.getHeader();
  message.setField(new OrigClOrdID("3434"));
  header.setField(new BeginString("FIX.4.1"));
  header.setField(new SenderCompID("BANZAI"));
  header.setField(new TargetCompID("EXEC"));
  header.setField(new MsgType("D"));
  message.setField(new OrigClOrdID("123"));
  message.setField(new ClOrdID("321"));
  message.setField(new HandlInst('3')); //CHANGE THIS TO RANDOM VALUE TO SEE WHAT HAPPENS
  message.setField(new OrdType('1'));
  message.setField(new Symbol("LNUX"));
  message.setField(new TransactTime(LocalDateTime.now()));
  message.setField(new Side(Side.BUY));
  message.setField(new Text("Cancel My Order!"));

  quickFixJTemplate.send(message);
}
}
```

And my server code base literally just has a main method and thats it:

```
@EnableQuickFixJServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When i start both apps, I can see the logon request/response and the heartbeats on the output of both apps. But when i call the endpoint in the client app; I get the following error:

`quickfix.FieldException: Tag not defined for this message type, field=41`. Why is this the case as I have set it on the message?

Futhermore, just a question i thought of;
This [class](https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter-examples/blob/master/simple-client/src/main/java/io/allune/quickfixj/spring/boot/starter/examples/client/ApplicationMessageCracker.java) in one of the examples extends MessageCracker.. let's assume the following scenario: the client talks to 2 servers; one server communicating in 4.1 and the other sever communicating on 4.2. If both servers sent a orderCancelRequest message, then how would it know which version of the protocol to parse the message in? I ask this because in the config [class](https://github.com/esanchezros/quickfixj-spring-boot-starter-examples/blob/master/simple-client/src/main/java/io/allune/quickfixj/spring/boot/starter/examples/client/AppClient.java#L52) they're wiring in one message cracker for the app so what if your client needs to handle multiple version of fix? How would this be achieved?

Comment: That `FieldException` is telling you the opposite: you set the field on the message but it is not defined in the counterparty's DataDictionary for that message type and hence the message gets rejected.

Comment: Your second question: the `MessageCracker` is called after the message has been received. You would have separate Sessions for FIX4.1 and FIX4.2. If you wanted to use the same `MessageCracker` for both Sessions you can add similar callbacks for e.g. `quickfix.fix42.OrderCancelRequest`.